# Что делать, если дал ответ, но позже нашёл похожий вопрос с похожим (но менее развёрнутым) ответом?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, нытьё, неотвеченные-вопросы, запоздалые-ответы

**Небольшая предыстория ситуациии:** Я ещё изучаю `java`, поэтому далеко не на все вопросы с меткой [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) могу ответить. Решил дать ответ на какой-нибудь вопрос, но новые вопросы с меткой [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) оказались мне не по зубам.

**Сама ситуация:** Таким образом я решил дать ответ на один из старых, т.е неотвеченых вопросов. И я нашёл вопрос, на который нет ответов и я могу ответить. [Вот сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320034/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0/1505052#1505052).

Я написал на него подробный и понятный ответ (как мне кажется). Но через некоторое время на вопрос был поставлен минус. Но даже не в минусе, а в том, что через некоторое время под вопросом возник такой комментарий:

> Похоже на [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610430/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc/610439#610439)

Я перешёл по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610430/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc/610439#610439) и увидел, что есть похожий по смыслу вопрос, который был задан на несколько лет раньше и на него уже есть ответ!

Сначала я расстроился: ну вот, старался, писал ответ, а теперь его удалять... Но потом оценил ситуацию получше и понял: ответы всё-таки хоть и похожи, но в тоже время и различаются. Мой ответ более подробный и в нём я показываю "работу  под капотом" с примерами кода.

**Вопрос:** что делать с моим ответом. У меня есть несколько вариантов:

- Перенести ответ в вопрос, где на него уже есть ответ, но немного менее подробный;
- Удалить ответ вообще (не хотелось бы, но если долг велит, то обязан так поступить);
- Ответ не переносит и не удалять, но написать (в коментариях) чем он отличается от ответа на похожий вопрос и возможно, дополнить ответ;
- Перенести ответ и написать (в коментариях) чем он отличается от ответа на похожий вопрос и возможно, дополнить ответ (то есть всё тоже самое, что и в прежнем пункте, только с переносом);
- Оставить всё как есть и ничего не делать, *"и так сойдёт"* (мне этот вариант не нравиться, иначе бы я не задавал бы вопрос на мете);
- (вариант `@Kromster` из комментария) так как вопрос, на который я дал ответ имеет больше голосов (10 против 2), то объединить вопросы вокруг вопроса с 10-ю голосами;

Как лучше поступить?

**P.S** в комментариях мне ещё написали, что мой ответ в приниципе верен. Но что-то на ответе уже три минуса (правда есть один голос "за"). Может, из-за того, что он похож на другой?

Comment: Можно замержить со старым уже отвеченным вопросом. И ваш ответ сохранится, и дубликат вопроса уйдёт.

Comment: @Nofate то есть "Перенести ответ в вопрос, где на него уже есть ответ, но немного менее подробный?"

Comment: Не совсем. Вы инициируете закрытие вопроса как дубликата. После этого модератор использует специальное действие "Объединение вопросов", чтобы перенести все ответы с дубликата на основной вопрос.

Comment: @Nofate то есть я должен на вопрос оставить тревогу "дубликат" и попросить модератора объединить вопросы?

Comment: 1 - дать текущему вопросу нормальное название (например "что делать если я дал ответ на вопрос у которого позже нашелся потенциальный дубликат?". 2 - к сожалению не шарю в Java, но по виду, ваш ответ и вопрос на который он дан лучше и популярнее, т.ч. было бы вероятно лучше тот другой вопрос к вашему приклеить (несмотря на то что он старше). 3 - на минус не обращайте внимания, без пояснения он больше похож на мисклик или чью-то личную неприязнь.

Comment: @Nofate вопрос закрыли как дубликат. А дальше-то как?

Comment: @Зонтик готово, смержено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы стал такой вариант (идея `@Nofate♦`, и его же реализация):

1. Сначала закрыть [более новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320034/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0/1505052#1505052)(правда более популярный) как дубликат [более старого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610430/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc/610439#610439).
2. Попросить модератора объединить вопросы.

Плюсы такого подхода:

1. Все ответы - в одном месте (а ведь наш сайт - база знаний).
2. Никто не подозревает меня в плагиате и не минусует ответ за это.
3. Ничего не надо удалять.